# How to remove first 0's (zero) from string in c# 2.0

Tags: c#

I have a string that can contain a value like 000232 or 999999 or 023000
What I am trying to do is to remove the first 000 from the first string, leave the second string and remove the first 0 from the third string and keep 000 to the right

How do I best perfrom this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`String.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx):

```
// s is string
string trimmed = s.TrimStart('0');
```

Please note that it is essential that you assign the result of `String.TrimStart` to a variable of type `string`. In .NET, `string`s are immutable and therefore `String.TrimStart` does not modify the `string` that the method is invoked on. That is, `s.TrimStart('0')` does not modify `s`. If you want to modify `s` you must say

```
s = s.TrimStart('0');
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use a regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string x = "000232";
x = Regex.Replace(x, "^0*", "");
```

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems."

Answer (score 0):

```
int valueInt;
if (int.TryParse(valueString, out valueInt))
    result = valueInt.ToString();
else
    result = string.Empty;
```